# SpringBoot login page that use email and password from database and can successfully login?

Tags: mysql, forms, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I want to create a log in page with spring boot and mysql. I first create a sign up page that take input from user end and store the data in mysql database. I want to log in on the same database that is stored in mysql database. I not want to use the spring security for this purpose. How can i get login when i will enter the email and password means how can i validate the data that is matched and i can successfully login.

```
Model Class
-----------

@Entity
@Table (name = "user_details")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    @NotBlank(message = "email is mandatory")
    private String email;
    private int phone;
    private int password;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                ", phone=" + phone +
                ", password=" + password +
                '}';
    }


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public int getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(int phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public int getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(int password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

```
Repository Class:
----------
@Repository
public interface UserRepo1 extends CrudRepository<User,Long> {
}
```

```
Controller Class
----------------

@Controller
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    UserRepo1 userRepo1;

    @GetMapping ("/")
    public String showSignUpForm(User user){
        return "sign-up";
    }

    @PostMapping ("/signup")
    public String addUser(@Valid User user, BindingResult result, Model model){
        if(result.hasErrors()){
            return "sign-up";
        }
        userRepo1.save(user);
        model.addAttribute("users",userRepo1.findAll());
        return "result";
    }

}
```

```
Sign up
-------

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="htt://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="form" style="text-align:center" >

  <ul class="tab-group">
    <li class="tab active"><a href="#signup">Sign Up</a></li>
    <li class="tab"><a href="#login">Log In</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="signup">
      <h1>Sign Up for Free</h1>

      <form action="/" th:action="@{/signup}" th:object="${user}" method="post" >

        <div class="top-row">
          <div class="field-wrap">
            <label>
              Name<span class="req">:</span>
            </label>
            <input type="text" th:field="*{name}" id="name" placeholder="Name">
             </div>
        </div>

        <div class="field-wrap">
          <label>
            Email<span class="req">:</span>
          </label>
          <input type="email" th:field="*{email}" id="email" placeholder="Email">
          <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('email')}" th:errors="*{email}"></span>
        </div>
          <div class="field-wrap">
              <label>
                  Phone<span class="req">:</span>
              </label>
              <input type="tel" th:field="*{phone}" id="phone" placeholder="phone">
          </div>

          <div class="field-wrap">
              <label>
                  Password<span class="req">:</span>
              </label>
              <input type="password" th:field="*{password}" id="password" placeholder="password">
              <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('password')}" th:errors="*{password}"></span>
          </div>

          <input type="submit" value="submit">
      </form>

    </div>
  </div><!-- tab-content -->
</div> <!-- /form -->
</body>
</html>
```

```
Log In

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="login">
    <h1>Welcome Back!</h1>

    <form action="/" method="post">

        <div class="field-wrap">
            <label>
                Email Address<span class="req">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="email"required autocomplete="off"/>
        </div>

        <div class="field-wrap">
            <label>
                Password<span class="req">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="password"required autocomplete="off"/>
        </div>

        <p class="forgot"><a href="#">Forgot Password?</a></p>

        <button class="button button-block"/>Log In</button>

    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, Never store raw passwords. Encrypt it before storing it into the database. Better algorithm could be BCryptPasswordEncoder which does not have any decryption logic hence makes your encryption safe. And while comparing the data with real password you can use .matches method which compares only after encrypting it. Please go through the document to know more about it.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/crypto/bcrypt/BCryptPasswordEncoder.html

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it:

i) Add this to Controller:

```
@PostMapping("/welcome")
public String getWelcome(User user, Model model) {
    String email = user.getEmail();
    String password = user.getPassword();
    User userByEmail = userRepo1.findByEmail(email);
    boolean status;
    String message;

    if(userByEmail != null) {
        if(password.equals(userByEmail.getPassword())) {
            status = true;
        }
        else {
            status = false;
        }
    }
    else {
        status = false;
    }

    if(status) {
        message = "Login Successful";
    }
    else {
        message = "Login Unsuccessful";
    }

    model.addAttribute("message", message);
    return "welcome";
}
```

ii)

Change UserRepo1 to:

```
public interface UserRepo1 extends CrudRepository<User,Long> {
    User findByEmail(String email);
}
```

iii)

Change result.html to:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="login">
    <h1>Welcome Back!</h1>

    <form action="/" th:action="@{/welcome}" th:object="${user}" method="post" >

        <div class="field-wrap">
            <label>
                Email Address<span class="req">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="email" th:field="*{email}" required autocomplete="off"/>
        </div>

        <div class="field-wrap">
            <label>
                Password<span class="req">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="password" th:field="*{password}" required autocomplete="off"/>
        </div>

        <p class="forgot"><a href="#">Forgot Password?</a></p>

        <button class="button button-block">Log In</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

iv) Create an HTML file called 'welcome.html' and add the following to the file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <h1 th:text="${message}"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

N.B.: Store password and phone number as a String.